# combine two methods in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class with 2 methods. 
I would like to print out some text using both methods

```
class ceasar:
    plain = ""
    cipher = ""
    shift = 0

    def encrypt (self, plain):
        newStr = ""
        excludedLetters = ['a','e','i','o','u',' '] # best varible name ever
        for letter in plain:
            if not(letter in excludedLetters): # exclude the letters in excludedLetters
                newStr = newStr + letter # addes letters one by one into newStr
        return newStr

    def encryptTwo(self, plain, shift):
        cipherStr = ""    
        for letter in plain:
            cipher = ord(letter) + shift
            cipherStr = cipherStr + chr(cipher)
        return cipherStr

c = ceasar() # use ceasar class as c
```

if I try to print it as

```
print c.encrypt(c.plain)
```

it will remove the vowels and spaces.

```
print c.encryptTwo(c.plain, c.shift)
```

will shift it (its on user input)

but how to combine them if someone wants to remove vowel and shift it?
I could type out the ways I tried to get it to work but it would clutter up the post with lovely errors

Comment: You can add one more method in your class that have combined functionality of both.

Comment: You should make shift etc..  attributes and pass them in  `def __init__(self, plain, ciphe, shiftr):`

Comment: please do *clutter up the post with lovely errors*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>What I think you want is</s>

```
print c.encryptTwo(c.encrypt(c.plain), c.shift)
```

which will execute `encryptTwo` with the result of `encrypt`.

If, however, you want to remove vowels from the result, then

```
print c.encrypt(c.encryptTwo(c.plain, c.shift))
```

is what you want.

Comment: If the input is "abc"  and I shift it 3 it will print out "ef"

seems to remove the "a" from the input and shift it all 3 like that

Comment: @jaylow, that is exactly what your code is doing, what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: it is supposed to be a caesar cipher that also remove the vowels and white space to make it harder, so "abc" would end up as "df"

("abc" shifted 3 would be "def" but removing the e from it.)

Comment: @jaylow, and how to you plan on putting it back together?

Comment: not, I just want to remove it. i did ask my teacher the same thing and he said it was not needed for this, i am just stuck on how to print it out that it removes the vowels and shifts it. if  it will work i will need to find out how to read in a file and do the same to it. was testing some stuff out but got error about strings and what not, but tried to less to ask about that issue.

Comment: @jaylow: do you want to remove the vowels from the input, the result, or both?

Comment: @Michael: the result

Answer (score 0):

I would take plain and shift as parameters in init, you can also use *str.translate* to remove the vowels and spaces, you can also forget cipher as you never use it, also plain is set to an empty string to I don't see how self.plain could give you any result

```
class ceasar(object):
    def __init__(self, plain,  shift):
        self.plain = plain
        self.shift = shift

    def remove(self):
        return self.plain.translate(None, "aeiou ")

    def encrypt(self, new):
        return "".join([chr(ord(letter) + self.shift) for letter in new])
```

It will remove vowels and spaces and then shift the remainder but I don't see how you are going to put the string back together, if you just used the logic in encryptTwo  you could shift back but I don't see the logic in removing letters if you plan on decrytping:

```
In [2]: c = ceasar("foobar", 3) 

In [3]: c.encryptTwo(c.encrypt())
Out[3]: 'ieu'

In [4]: c = ceasar("foobar", 3)

In [5]: c.encrypt(c.remove())
Out[5]: 'ieu'

In [6]: c.plain
Out[6]: 'foobar'

In [7]: c.encrypt(c.plain)
Out[7]: 'irredu'
In [11]: c = ceasar("abc", 3)

In [12]: c.encrypt(c.remove())
Out[12]: 'ef'
```

If you want to use a single method and give the user the option of what to remove, set a flag in encrypt:

```
class ceasar(object):
    def __init__(self, plain,  shift, ignore):
        self.plain = plain
        self.shift = shift
        self.ignore = set(ignore)

    def encrypt(self,remove=False):
        if remove:
            return "".join([chr(ord(letter) + self.shift) for letter in self.plain if letter not in self.ignore])
        return "".join([chr(ord(letter) + self.shift) for letter in self.plain])
```

passing True will remove whatever is in ignore or else use each char:

```
In [18]: c = ceasar("abc", 3,"aeiou ")

In [19]: c.encrypt(True)
Out[19]: 'def'

In [20]: c.encrypt()
Out[20]: 'ef'

In [21]: c.plain
Out[21]: 'abc'
```

You can also combine it with *str.translate*:

```
class ceasar(object):
    def __init__(self, plain,  shift, ignore):
        self.plain = plain
        self.shift = shift
        self.ignore = ignore

    def encrypt(self,remove=False):
        if remove:
            return "".join([chr(ord(letter) + self.shift) for letter in self.plain.translate(None, self.ignore)])
        return "".join([chr(ord(letter) + self.shift) for letter in self.plain])
```